# How to show message near the button in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been created student page using aspx and c#.

I have been result button, which shows student's marks. and also i have added editresult in dropdown.

Editresult link is used to insert,update marks for students.

Here is output
[screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/ejdjx7cnf/untitled.jpg)

For example:

student id is 176. If i didn't insert marks in editresult link means, the result button need to show "Marks didn't updated" near the result button.

For the what should i do, I'm new to .net.

Here is my source code:

If i already update student marks means, i used below code.

studententry.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnresult_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Button btn = (Button)(sender);
                Response.Write("<script>");
                Response.Write("window.open('studentresult.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank')");
                Response.Write("</script>");
            }
```

and here is studentresult.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresultentry", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textstudentid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Request.QueryString["id"]);                
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);                
                lbltamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
                lblenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
                lblmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
                lblscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
                lblsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialScience"].ToString();            
            }
        }
```

So when the result click button (above code) shows student marks. But i need to show "student marks didn't updated" near the result button, if i didn't update student marks.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The screenshot is so small... I thought it was a snapshot... (really hard to see)

Comment: here is my screenshot http://s3.postimg.org/t0sk9b3yb/untitled.jpg.. can you check @lan

Comment: can anyone guide me ? thanks

Comment: It is still very small... I can hardly see any letter, is this screenshot from smartphone?

Comment: I think screenshot is not important..I will explain.. in the bottom the last link is result button. and at the top there is dropdown lists, its include editresult .. that's it.

Comment: Ok, if you said so. Let's hope I do not mis-understand your situation here. Do you want to show the text "(blabla) not updated" using `Label` near the result button (cause I cannot see)? do you have `Label` control nearby? And you want to show it if the update on the database fails, is this correct? this saying "didn't insert marks in editresult link" I may misunderstand without picture.

Comment: Nope.. i want to show that "(blabla) not updated"  using label.. that's why i posted .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complete method would be like this :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresultentry", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textstudentid.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Request.QueryString["id"]);                
                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds);     
                    if(adp.Fill(ds)==0)
                    {
                      lblNoresult.Text = "Marks didn't updated";
                    }
                    else
                    {           
                      lbltamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
                      lblenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
                      lblmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
                      lblscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
                      lblsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialScience"].ToString();  
                    }          
                }
            }
```

"Fill()" method returns the count of rows updated. If (adp.Fill(ds)==0), this means no record has been updated. In this case you need to update your label.

Answer (score 1):

May that I Understood your question:

1. **Editresult link is used to insert,update marks for students.(May be
   there is a table that stores Students Result).**
2. **If I didn't insert marks in editresult link means, the result button
   need to show "Marks didn't updated" near the result button.(If there is no    data in Students Result Table).**

Solution:

```
    protected void btnresult_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    Button btn = (Button)(sender);
                   //Get the row that contains this Button
                   GridViewRow gvr = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresultentry", con);
                   com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textstudentid.Text.Trim()); // Pass your required Parameters
                   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",btn.CommandArgument);                
                   SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                   adp.Fill(ds); 
                   if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
                   {              
                    Response.Write("<script>");
                    Response.Write("window.open('studentresult.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank')");
                    Response.Write("</script>");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     Label LabelID = gvr.Cells[columnNo].FindControl("lblId") as Label;
                     LabelID.Text = "Marks didn't updated";
                   }
                }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but your code shows lots of syntax error.. can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: What type of Error?You have to edit some code like "ColumnNo" , "lblId" and   `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textstudentid.Text.Trim());` -- as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Place a label control near the button and set the Text property to blank. Now after your insert/update operation based on the output you get from your method set the Labels text property from code-behind as Label.Text="whatever message you want to show".

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more label like "lblNoresult" and set its value like :

```
if(adp.Fill(ds)==0)
{
 lblNoresult.Text = "Marks didn't updated";
}
```

Comment: u can add it inside "protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)" method of studentresult.aspx.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `MessageBox.Show("text")`
Also you can create a label and leave it enpty until you want to show a message, let that label's name be `label1` for example:

```
label1.Text = "text";
```